# Convert incrementing pandas array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a column that goes:

```
[0,0,1,2,3,0,1,0,1,2]
```

Every time the column restarts at 0, that indicates a new cycle. I want to indicate those cycle iterations with an incrementing array. So the first value is its own cycle. The second through fifth values are part of their own cycles, etc.

```
[1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4]
```

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: `(df.col_name==0).cumsum()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can using `diff` with `cumsum`

```
s.diff().le(0).cumsum()+1
Out[300]: 
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
7    4
8    4
9    4
dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you said "column", so i'm guessing you're actually using pandas, but a basic, albeit not pretty, way with lists (like you show in your question):

```
l1 = [0,0,1,2,3,0,1,0,1,2]

l2 = [1]
c = 1
for i in range(1, len(l1)):
    if l1[i] != l1[i-1] + 1:
        c += 1
    l2.append(c)
```